# dompdf is not rendering PDF with more then 10 pages

Tags: php, dompdf

Currently, I am using `dompdf` for generating PDF but it's not rendering with more than 10 pages, Whenever I tried with more than 10 pages it returns blank page and gives following error.

**Fatal error**: `Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2358 bytes) in /home/my_file_path/dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php on line 4927`

Following is PHP script for generating pdf using `dompdf`

```
<?php

require '../dompdf/vendor/autoload.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
//$custom_labels=ob_get_flush();
$dompdf->loadHtml($custom_labels);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF

$dompdf->render();
echo "<pre>";print_r($custom_labels);
exit();


// Output the generated PDF to Browser
// $dompdf->stream();

// save file to location
$output = $dompdf->output();
$customLabel = "../admin/pdf/label/custom_".$orderComplete[0].".pdf";
if(!empty($orderComplete))
{
    file_put_contents($customLabel, $output);
    $relPath[] = $customLabel;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to increase the memory limit here.

If you can access `php.ini` then, you can change the following parameter

```
 memory_limit = 64M;
```

Or you can try changing it for that script only by adding this in the beginning.

```
 ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

Comment: I got new error : Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: then you have to access `php.ini` file and change the value there.

Comment: IN php.ini showing memory_limit 32M in local value and 512M in master value

Comment: change the local value then.

Comment: We have set value 512M in local but still not working ,given blank page

Comment: and what about the PDF?